# Javascript, regex: Replace specified characters with space and matched character

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to use javascript `replace()` with a regex expression so that when it matches certain characters like: `.,!?` it will replace the matched character with itself surrounded by spaces. For example the string `"hello?!?"` will become `"hello ?  !  ? "`.

Is there a better way than just doing a `string.replace()` for each character I wish replace?

I know I can select on the characters easy enough with `'/[!\?\.]/g'`, but getting it to replace it with the same character it matched with is eluding me.

Comment: Should there be one or two spaces between `?` and `!` in your example?

Comment: Either way, after I split the sentence using / +/g which accounts for any number of spaces being between them to account for user error

Comment: If the number of spaces does not matter then the answer of LeonardChallis is the one you are looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's as simple as adding a back-reference, like so:

```
"hello?!?".replace(/([!?\,\.])/g, ' $1 ');
```

Comment: Is there any sort of escape for the back reference? Doing the above gives me "hello $1  $1  $1".

Comment: This will add two spaces between consecutive special characters.

Comment: @Scott101 I edited to escape the period in the regex, as well as add the comma in your request above.  If you copy/paste the line above and run it in the js console in your browser, it works as requested.

Comment: @go-oleg That is ok for what I am doing as I immediately split the string using / +/g. The string is user input that I need to break up and I don't trust them to not put in multiple spaces between words.

Comment: @Tracker1 Awesome thanks, forgot to surround the regex in the parentheses. I'll have to wait to accept the answer in 3 min as stack overflow won't let me accept it yet.

Answer (score 0):

If `'/[!\?.]/g'` matches as a regex, just capture the group by surrounding it with ()'s
   '/([!\?.])/g'

Then use the returned matched group to get the character you matched